# how to resize cifar10 image from 32x32 to 227x227?

Tags: python, deep-learning, image-resizing, keras

I have read the image from cifar-10-batches-python

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imresize
# read data
data_dir = "F:\\dataSet\\cifar-10-batches-py"
testdata_dir="F:\\dataSet\\cifar-10-batches-py\\test_batch"
da=np.load(testdata_dir)
testdata=da['data']
testlabel=np.array(da['labels'])

train=np.empty((50000,3072))
label=np.empty((50000,))
for i in range(1,2):
    str='data_batch_'+np.str(i)
    path1=os.path.join(data_dir,str)
    data=np.load(path1)
    train[10000*(i-1):10000*i,:]=data['data']
    label[10000*(i-1):10000*i,]=data['labels']

def intlabel(label):
    for i in range(label.shape[0]):
        label[i,]=int(float(label[i,]))
    return label

def intdata(data):
    n=data.shape[0]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(3072):
            data[i,j]=int(float(data[i,j]))
    return data

label,train=intlabel(label),intdata(train)
train,label=np.array(train),np.array(label)
train = train.reshape(train.shape[0], 3, 32,32)
train = train.astype('float32')
```

then I don't know how to resize the data.
I used the imreszie function to resize image, but the effect was not good

Comment: You want to upscale an image to 7 times its original size, it will never "look good" as no algorithm can recover all the information that is just not there.

Comment: I want upscale the cifar10 image to fit AlexNet,vgg,ResNet

Comment: Don't do that, it is not going to work.

Comment: why? the papers proposing those network framework show it works.

Comment: They crop images from Imagenet, which are bigger than 227x227, not upscale an image that is 8 times smaller.

Comment: they also make an experiment on cifar10

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy can you proof your claim with a publication? I know papers where it worked fine :-)

Comment: @user3352632 No, its just my opinion, it does not make much sense to upscale so much, and of course it all depends on your definition of "worked fine".

Answer (score 1):

You can use opencv to pre-process the images-

```
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread('IMAGE_LOCATION')
img_fin = cv2.resize(img, (227, 227))
```

Comment: the data form I read is 50000x3072, as you said, I should reshape it to 50000x3x32x32, then save it as image, then resize, then read image.....,that is too complexity